# How can I display Loading UI based different complex when I search records using Room in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

The following code is from the [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/24509368-repository-pattern-with-jetpack-compose).

It will spend time to query records using `wordRepository.allWords()`, so author set  `_isLoading.value = true` first, then query records, finally `set _isLoading.value = false` in `fun load()`.

I think the author hope to keep displaying `LoadingUi()` with long time when query is more complex.

But I think there are some problems with these code.

The `suspend fun allWords(): Flow<PagingData<Word>>` is **cold flow**, so the `suspend fun allWords()` will return at once,  and `_isLoading.value = false` will be launched quickly  in Code B.  I think `LoadingUi()` will keep displaying the same time no matter there is 3000 records or 10 records.

Is there some problem with the solution ? I hope the `LoadingUi()` keep displaying with long time when query need to handle 3000 records, and `LoadingUi()` keep displaying with short time when query need to handle 10 records.

**Code A**

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      viewModel.load()
      setContent {
       ...
      val isLoading by viewModel.isLoading.collectAsState(false)
      WordsTheme {
         when {
            isLoading -> LoadingUi()
            else -> WordListUi(...)
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }


class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

  private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(true)
  val isLoading: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isLoading

  fun load() = effect {
    _isLoading.value = true
    allWords.value = wordRepository.allWords()
    _isLoading.value = false
  }

  private fun effect(block: suspend () -> Unit) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { block() }
  }
} 

 class WordRepository(...) {
   suspend fun allWords(): Flow<PagingData<Word>> = wordStore.ensureIsNotEmpty().all()
   suspend fun allWords(term: String): Flow<PagingData<Word>> = wordStore.ensureIsNotEmpty().all(term) 
    ...
 }
```

**Code B**

```
fun load() = effect {
    _isLoading.value = true
           
   //suspend fun allWords(): Flow<PagingData<Word>> is cold Flow, 
   //wordRepository.allWords() will return at once no matter there is 3000 records or 10 records
    allWords.value = wordRepository.allWords()  
    
    _isLoading.value = false    
 }
```

**The added content:**

The first run Code C:   E/My: Duration for Return: 57

The second run Code C:   E/My: Duration for Return: 1099

A cold stream does not start producing values until one starts to collect them, so I think it will spend the same time between *The first run* and *The second run*.

The `suspend fun allWords(): Flow<PagingData<Word>>` is cold flow, I think it will return at once, why does it spend different time between *The first run* and *The second run*?

**Code C ( I modified )**

```
 fun load() = effect {
    _isLoading.value = true

    val a = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis //I add
    allWords.value = wordRepository.allWords()
    val b = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis //I add

    Log.e("My","Duration for Return: "+(b-a))  //I add

    _isLoading.value = false
  }


  //I modify
  suspend fun allWords(): Flow<PagingData<Word>> {
     //delay(10)      //The first run
     delay(1000)      //The second run
     return wordStore.ensureIsNotEmpty().all()
  }

  //I modify
  suspend fun allWords(term: String): Flow<PagingData<Word>> {
    //delay(10)       //The first run
    delay(1000)   //The second run
    return   wordStore.ensureIsNotEmpty().all(term)
  }        

  private suspend fun WordStore.ensureIsNotEmpty() = apply {
     if (isEmpty()) {
       val words = wordSource.load()
       save(words) 
     }      
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problems with this solution. Function `allWords()` defined in the `WordRepository` as the following:

```
suspend fun allWords(): Flow<PagingData<Word>> = wordStore.ensureIsNotEmpty().all()

private suspend fun WordStore.ensureIsNotEmpty() = apply {
    if (isEmpty()) {
      val words = wordSource.load()
      save(words)
    }
}
```

Here when calling `allWords()` function `ensureIsNotEmpty()` is executed first (it can take some time because of network call - `wordSource.load()`), and then `.all()` function returns the `Flow`.

Function `wordSource.load()` makes a network request using `Dispatchers.IO` context and defined in the `WordSource` as the following:

```
suspend fun load(): List<Word> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {     
    client.getRemoteWords() 
      .lineSequence()       
      .map { Word(it) }     
      .toList()             
}
```

So `wordRepository.allWords()` makes a network request and it can take some time to execute, therefore function `load()` in the `MainViewModel` seems correct:

```
fun load() = effect {
    _isLoading.value = true
    allWords.value = wordRepository.allWords()
    _isLoading.value = false
}
```

---

> A cold stream does not start producing values until one starts to collect them.

That is correct, but in the `allWords()` function before a `Flow` is returned, delay happens:

```
suspend fun allWords(): Flow<PagingData<Word>> {
   delay(1000)      // delay before wordStore.ensureIsNotEmpty().all() function returns a Flow
   return wordStore.ensureIsNotEmpty().all()
}
```

That's why you have different time of execution.

You may got confused because the return type of `allWords()` is `Flow` but the function doesn't create the flow by itself.

> so I think it will spend the same time between The first run and The second run.

For that to happen the `allWords()` function should produce `Flow` by itself using `flow` builder:

```
fun allWords(): Flow<PagingData<Word>> = flow { 
   delay(1000) 
   ... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  but I hope the `LoadingUi()` can keep displaying with long time when `wordRepository.allWords()` is long time operation, and `LoadingUi()` keep displaying with less time when `wordRepository.allWords()` is short time operation. I think that  `LoadingUi()` will keep displaying the same time no matter the `wordRepository.allWords()` is fast or slow in Code A.

Comment: You know that the `suspend fun allWords(): Flow<PagingData<Word>>`  is clod flow, so `wordRepository.allWords()` will return quickly.

Comment: For sample, I hope the Loading UI  to display 5 seconds when `wordRepository.allWords()` need to handle 3000 records, and the Loading UI  to display 2 seconds when `wordRepository.allWords()` only need to handle 10 records.

Comment: `wordRepository.allWords()` will not return quickly if network request is made. `Flow` is returned after network request is made in `ensureIsNotEmpty()` method.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: Did you check what does `isEmpty()` function return? It may be the case that it returns `false` and the the block after `if` statement is not executed `if (isEmpty()) {
      ...
      // not executed because isEmpty() returns false
      delay(10)        //The first time
      //delay(100000)  // The second time
    }`

Comment: Thanks! I modify the code, you are right.

Comment: The `suspend fun allWords(): Flow<PagingData<Word>>` is clod flow, I think it will return at once, why does it spend different time between `The first run` and `The second run`?

Comment: A cold stream does not start producing values until one starts to collect them, so I think it  will spend the same time between `The first run` and `The second run`!

Comment: It's because the `Flow` is returned after the delay. `wordStore.ensureIsNotEmpty().all()` here first `ensureIsNotEmpty()` is executed (it can take some time because of  network call or delays), and then `.all()` function returns the `Flow`.

Comment: I updated my answer with this information.

Comment: Thanks! I update my code in `The Added Content` part.

Comment: So I still think they will spend the same time between `The first run` and `The second run`, but in fact, I'm wrong ,why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243475/discussion-between-sergey-and-hellocw).